# How to load an External Html file in servlet?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I want to load an Predefined Html file in my servlet code:-

this is my html file:-index.html

```
<html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
         <p> This is the msg to be displayed on servlet </p>
     </body>
</html>
```

This is load page function:-

```
   function loadPage(href)
            {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", href, false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                return xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
This is my servlet code:-



      out.println("<html><head>");
            out.println("<script>");
            out.println("$(document).ready(function(){");
            out.println("document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = loadpage('index.html'");
            out.println(" });");
            out.println("</script>");
            out.println("</head><body>");
            out.println( "<h1 id='bottom' ></h1>");
            out.println("</body></html>");
```

where i am trying to add index.html page

Can anyone help me to sort this issue,
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is your servlet and your index.html file deployed (what are their URLs)? And how exactly does your `loadpage()` function work?

Comment: sorry this i didnot mention loadpage function there plz see now i have updated

Comment: Can you access the `index.html` page directly from the browser? Yf yes, what is its URL? And what is the URL of the servlet?

Comment: i am trying to make an dynmic web project where my index.html page is in webcontent folder

Comment: URLs, please! http://localhost:8080/youApp/index.html or so. Or add the structure of your web app and its `web.xml` file to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 out.println("document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = loadpage('index.html'");
```

So when the above lines are executed, you expect the 'index.html' page to load. Is that it ?

On a servlet this is just a String that is flushed to the browser. This html/script then executes on the browser.

You have at least two ways to achieve this

1. On the browser - Make an ajax call that returns the html. Substitute the response as the innerHTML of your dom element.
2. On the server - Use a request dispatcher to include the html. This, IMHO, is an easier option for your problem.

out.println("document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = '");
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").include(request,response); 
out.println("';");